# composite primary key definition doesn't act as composite in jdbc

Tags: sql, derby

I'm working with apache derby jdbc (in netbeans 7.2.1)
I want to create table with composite primary key (so that only the composition of these 4 columns values is unique, and value of each one of them separately is not unique)

```
Create table MovieScreens(
NameM  varchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
DateS DATE NOT NULL UNIQUE,
Hall NUMERIC NOT NULL  UNIQUE,
HourS NUMERIC  NOT NULL  UNIQUE,
SEATSFREE  varchar (500) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (Hall) REFERENCES Halls(Hall),
FOREIGN KEY (NameM) REFERENCES MoviesDetails(NAMEM),
**primary key (NameM , DateS,Hall,HourS)**
)
```

But it seems each of the columns defined as primary key is primary key by itself, and not part of the composite key. When I try to insert rows that differ only by one of these values, I get error:

```
Error code -1, SQL state 23505: The statement was aborted because it would have caused a duplicate key value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index .
```

As I understand netbeans uses MySQL database, and this should be the right syntax for MySQL, or am I wrong?

Any input would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You set the fields composing your primary key as `UNIQUE` so each one of them cannot have twice the same value. Remove this constraint and just keep the primary key declaration.

By the way, your problem is only related to pure SQL.. Using JDBC has no impact on this.

Comment: Thank you! It was indeed the problem

Comment: @qwerty You're welcome. You can then mark the mark the answer as accepted so people having the same problem can easily see there is a working answer.